# C# variable contents altered when using a debugger

Tags: c#, .net, xml, debugging, variables

In my C# program, I parse an XML file, which has been created before with XSLT. When I normally run the program, variable extraClasses contains 3 nodes. The problem is that the selector I am using must return 2 nodes when applied to this specific XML.

Trying to find the bug in my code, I used a debugger. When I examined the value of variable `extraClasses`, the node count was 2, and the result was the expected. When the variable is not examined, node count is 3 and the results are wrong.

Furthermore, when I add an `if` statement to check if the `extraClasses` count is more than 2, after the assignment, my program works fine (extraClasses.Count = 2).

Why is this happening? Why the value examination alters the contents of the variable? I am using C# and .NET Framework 4.

```
var extraClasses = xml.SelectNodes("//Class[@level='2']");  

foreach (XmlElement extraClass in extraClasses) {
/* create some new nodes and append to the xml */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because the extraClasses.GetEnumerator().MoveNext is invoked when you 'touch' it in debugmode. This way you'll *lose* an element. This is probably because a **yield return** within the SelectNodes is used.

You could try this:

```
var extraClasses = new List<XmlElement>( xml.SelectNodes("//Class[@level='2']") );  

foreach (XmlElement extraClass in extraClasses) {
/* create some new nodes and append to the xml */
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The XmlNodeList that SelectNodes returns does not have a method .ToArray()

Comment: Updated it, Too bad the XnlNodeList hasn't got a ToArray() or ToList|(), You can create a list, passing the xml.SelectNodes into it's constructor.

Comment: Managed to solve the problem by using:
    var extraClasses = new List<XmlNode>(xml.SelectNodes("//Class[@level='2']").Cast<XmlNode>());

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem by using:

```
var extraClasses = new List<XmlNode>(xml.SelectNodes("//Class[@level='2']").Cast<XmlNode>());
```